# Meteor Inserting Array Into Collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

Have a simple question here,

Im trying to insert an array of 'bidders', into my collection, for an ebay-clone
Currently, my attempt to do this is

```
Auctions.insert({book: "booktest", school: "University", owner: "owner", bidders: ['bidder1', 'bidder2']});
```

I've played around and have found out that the issue is coming from the bidders field. I always get the error

```
 Exception from Tracker recompute function: Error: Can't call non-function: test
```

I still get this error when bidders has nothing in its array.

My question is, can anyone explain to my why I cannot insert this array into the Auctions collection?

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from the line you highlighted?

Comment: Yes because when I insert the object with the bidders field it works fine

Comment: You are getting `Error: Can't call non-function: test`, so you may be calling `test()` somewhere, but have not defined a `function test(){ ... }`. Meteor/Mongo has no problem with an array value in a collection.

Comment: You were correct! But In turn another question came up. I was referring to bidders in my html as {{bidders[0]}} to output the first bidder, however, it only works if i say {{bidders}}, and it outputs all the bidders. How would I access only a specific element of the array?

Comment: are you looping through the bidders? IF so, I'd use a {{#each}} block helper and then define "bidders" using a template helpers.

Template.myTemplate.helpers({ bidders: function(){ return this.bidders } });

Then, inside the {{#each}} helpers you can just call {{this}} to get the bidder.